# how to update the status of a row in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update the status of a row in my `Funds` table using a button.
Here is my controller:

```
public function changeStatus(Funds $funds)
{
    if ($funds > status == false) {
        $funds->status = true;
        $funds->update(['status' => $funds->status]);

        return redirect('funds,index')->with('success', 'Good Job, Fund mark is done!');
    } else {
        $funds->status = true;
        $funds->update(['status' => $funds->status]);

        return redirect('funds.index')->with('success', ' Fund is pending!');
    }
}
```

then I created the route for `FundsController@changeStatus`:

```
Route::patch('transactions/{funds}/completed', 'FundsController@changeStatus');
```

The HTML code i used in the index.blade.php file

````
                <div class="card-body">
                   <table class="table table-bordered">
                     <thead>                  
                       <tr>
                         <th style="width: 10px">Account Number</th>
                         <th>Other Account Number</th>
                         <th>Remarks</th>
                         <th>acc_type</th>
                         <th>Status</th>
                         <th>Actions</th>
                       </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                     @foreach($funds as $fund)
                       <tr>
                         <td> {{ $fund->accno }} </td>
                         <td>{{ $fund->accnumber }}</td>
                         <td> {{ $fund->Remarks }} </td>
                         <td>{{ $fund->acc_type }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $fund->status }}</td>
                         <td>
                             {!! Form::model($fund, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['funds.changeStatus', $fund->id]]) !!}
                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">{{ $fund->status == false ? 'Marked Pending' : 'Marked complete' }}</button>
                             {!! Form::close() !!}
                         </td>
                       </tr>
                     @endforeach
                     </tbody>
                   </table>
 ```


but I ended up with this error:
> Undefined property: stdClass::$slug (View: C:\Users\user pc\Desktop\dkn\resources\views\funds\index.blade.php)

Where did I go wrong and how can I update funds status using this method?
````

Comment: can you add the route declaration for the `'funds.index'` route, also you have a typo in `if($funds>status == false)` should be `if($funds->status == false)`

Comment: are you sure that `$fund` variable is being passed to view file by your Controller which returns the index blade? Your `changeStatus` method is not passing it too.

Comment: and `redirect` helper uses route not a blade file should use `return view()`

Comment: @Ιησούς του ναυή this is the exact code

Comment: $funds->slug should be $fund->slug (This will remove your error)

Comment: @Bart i did that but it didn't work so i delete the $fund->slug , but ended up with this error **Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: transactions/{funds}/completed]. (View: C:\Users\user pc\Desktop\dkn\resources\views\funds\index.blade.php)**

Comment: please can anyone point out how i can get the result i want

Comment: After $funds->status use $funds->save() because you already called the model.

Comment: Please can you explain what didn't work when you changed `$funds->slug` to `$fund->slug`.

Comment: the funds.index page could not load instead i got the error **Undefined property: stdClass::$slug (View: C:\Users\user pc\Desktop\dkn\resources\views\funds\index.blade.php)**@Rwd

Comment: @TanvirAhmed but i want to update the status from false to true(the default value is 0).

Comment: Could you add the html code of funds.index?

Comment: And what is the error at the moment?

Comment: **Class App\Http\Controllers\Funds does not exist**

Comment: Can you update the full FundsController code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204828/discussion-between-toby-nwude-and-bart-van-venrooij).

Comment: can you give the screeenshot of dd($funds)

Comment: it's returns 0 but without dd($funds) it returns page not found @TanvirAhmed

Comment: my new controller is ```public function changeStatus(Funds $funds)
    {
        dd($funds->status);
        if ($funds->status == false) {
            $funds->update(['status' => true]);

            return redirect('funds.index')->with('success', 'Good Job, Fund mark is done!');
        } else {
            $funds->update(['status' => false]);

            return redirect('funds.index')->with('success', ' Fund is pending!');
        }
    }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oke you should first try to create a correct form.

First i would like to recommend you that you use named routes:

```
Route::patch('transactions/{funds}/completed', 'FundsController@changeStatus')->name('funds.changeStatus');
```

This will make it easier to get te correct route in your form. 
Then the form should look something like this:

```
Form::model($fund, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['funds.changeStatus', $fund->id]]);
```

If you want to use the slug (instead of the id):

```
Form::model($fund, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['funds.changeStatus', $fund->slug]]);
```

When you want to use the slug, make sure to add the following method to your Funds model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
public function changeStatus(Funds $funds)
{
    if ($funds->status == false) {
        $funds->update(['status' => true]);

        return redirect('funds.index')->with('success', 'Good Job, Fund mark is done!');
    } else {
        $funds->update(['status' => false]);

        return redirect('funds.index')->with('success', ' Fund is pending!');
    }
}
```

OR

```
public function changeStatus(Funds $funds)
{
    $funds->update(['status' => !$funds->status]);

    if ($funds->status == true) {
        return redirect('funds.index')->with('success', 'Good Job, Fund mark is done!');
    } else {
        return redirect('funds.index')->with('success', ' Fund is pending!');
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my form to this ```<td>
                                {!! Form::model($fund, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['funds.changeStatus', $fund]]) !!}
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">{{ $fund->status == false ? 'Marked Pending' : 'Marked complete' }}</button>
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                            </td>```

Comment: but i recieve this error **Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string (View: C:\Users\user pc\Desktop\dkn\resources\views\funds\index.blade.php)**

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your view address file is correct.

Comment: thanks i corrected the return view but that's not the issue i'm having